# Difference between $reactive(this).attach($scope) and $scope.viewModel(this)

Tags: angular-meteor

In Angular "Todo App" tutorial on official [meteor.com](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/creating-an-app) website in constructor there's:

```
$scope.viewModel(this);
```

In "Socially" tutorial on [angular-meteor.com](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/bootstrapping) it looks like the very same thing is achieved by:

```
$reactive(this).attach($scope)
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I did some research on the subject and here is what I found out.

Regarding **$reactive(this).attach($scope)**:

> "$reactive is a service that takes care of the reactivity of your
> Meteor data, and updates your AngularJS code."
>
> "This service wraps context (can be used with this or $scope) - so you
> can use it with any context as you wish."

Read details about it [here](https://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.0/reactive).

Regarding **$scope.viewModel(this)**:

It looks like it is a package, a library:

> "ViewModel is a view layer for Meteor. You can think of it as Angular,
> Knockout, Aurelia, Vue, etc. but without the boilerplate code required
> to make those work."

More information about it [here](https://viewmodel.org/).

Comment: No, the tutorial in question doesn't use that viewmodel package.